# How to get value and list from Future with custom model in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am calling an API to get data from server and i try make a dart file (model). after get in a field value and all data show list. but i cannot found how to make. i was try many options but always take a syntax error or diffrent errors.
my getdata work i can print console but can't take in value.
have a easy way?

my json;

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "User List",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_name": "user1",
            "user_f_name": "User",
            "comp_type": "AGN",
            "comp_depr": "SALES",
            "comp_code": "AHN0001",
            "depr_job": "",
            "comp_code_sub": "",
            "private_1": "",
            "private_2": "",
            "create_user": "",
            "update_user": "",
            "created_at": 2021-09-06T21:01:01.000000Z,
            "updated_at": "2021-09-06T21:01:01.000000Z",
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "user_name": "user2",
            "user_f_name": "",
            "comp_type": "",
            "comp_depr": "",
            "comp_code": "",
            "depr_job": "",
            "comp_code_sub": "",
            "private_1": "",
            "private_2": "",
            "create_user": "",
            "update_user": "",
            "created_at": "2021-09-06T20:49:45.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-06T20:49:45.000000Z",
            "id": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

my code try one data;

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData3() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;
    final prefsu = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final keyu = 'user';
    final valueu = prefsu.get(keyu) ?? 0;
    var username = "$valueu";
   

    String myUrl =
        String myUrl = "$serverUrl/userchecks/$username";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });
   
    var data1 = json.decode(response.body);    
    print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    print(data1['user_f_name']);
      
    return (json.decode(response.body));
  }
```

my code try list data

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/userchecks";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });

    print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    final data1 = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data1['user_f_name']);

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: Please append your error message if possible.

Comment: for example last error message if try call a model and call give message 
return Userdprcheck.fromJson(response.data); "The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Response'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'."

if change code return Userdprcheck.fromJson(response.body); give error " The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."

Comment: on `json.decode(response.body)` use `json.decode(response.body)['data']`. Can you include your data mode. Then it would be easy to test

Comment: i take same error again. Future<Userdprcheck> getData3() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;   
         
    return Userdprcheck.fromJson(response.body)['data'];
  }
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: my example model : class Userdprcheck {
  String compType = 'cc';


  Userdprcheck({required this.compType});

  Userdprcheck.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    compType = json['comp_type'];
    
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['comp_type'] = this.compType;
    
    return data;
  }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ to create your data model from your json data

---

Here is UserData class:

```dart
class UserData {
    String? userName;
    String? userFName;
    String? compType;
    String? compDepr;
    String? compCode;
    String? deprJob;
    String? compCodeSub;
    String? private1;
    String? private2;
    String? createUser;
    String? updateUser;
    String? createdAt;
    String? updatedAt;
    int? id;

    UserData(
        {this.userName,
        this.userFName,
        this.compType,
        this.compDepr,
        this.compCode,
        this.deprJob,
        this.compCodeSub,
        this.private1,
        this.private2,
        this.createUser,
        this.updateUser,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.id});

    UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      userName = json['user_name'];
      userFName = json['user_f_name'];
      compType = json['comp_type'];
      compDepr = json['comp_depr'];
      compCode = json['comp_code'];
      deprJob = json['depr_job'];
      compCodeSub = json['comp_code_sub'];
      private1 = json['private_1'];
      private2 = json['private_2'];
      createUser = json['create_user'];
      updateUser = json['update_user'];
      createdAt = json['created_at'];
      updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
      id = json['id'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      data['user_name'] = userName;
      data['user_f_name'] = userFName;
      data['comp_type'] = compType;
      data['comp_depr'] = compDepr;
      data['comp_code'] = compCode;
      data['depr_job'] = deprJob;
      data['comp_code_sub'] = compCodeSub;
      data['private_1'] = private1;
      data['private_2'] = private2;
      data['create_user'] = createUser;
      data['update_user'] = updateUser;
      data['created_at'] = createdAt;
      data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
      data['id'] = id;
      return data;
    }
}
```

---

Then you can get your data from your server and transform it to your data model:

```dart
Future<List<UserData>> getUserData() async {
  const token = 'your_token';

  const myUrl = "your_url";

  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
  });

  // here you get your response data as Map
  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  // here you convert your data list to UserData list
  final userDataList = (responseData['data'] as List)
      .map((e) => UserData.fromJson(e))
      .toList();

  for (final element in userDataList) {
    // if you need comp_type you can get it from your model
    print(element.compType);
  }

  return userDataList;
}
```